# How do I replace the bulb in this headlight assembly?

Tags: headlight, jetta

I replaced a burned-out low beam bulb (H7) in my 2012 Jetta, but when I went to change the other side (driver's), the assembly was way different from the passenger side (which is what I expected based on tutorial videos). I showed pictures to a family member who suggested it was probably a DIY replacement by the previous owner. What is this assembly and how do I change the bulb?

The first picture is as I found it, and the second is after unplugging it. The plug came off easily, revealing the prongs from the back of the bulb, but nothing else moved easily.

[image: the back of a headlight assembly, plugged in]

[image: the back of an unplugged headlight assembly, showing the prongs on the end of the bulb]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Phillips head screwdriver, loosen the screw holding the wire clip. Pivot the wire clip upwards. If the clip won't pivot up, remove the screw; then pivot or remove the clip. When the clip is out of the way, the bulb can be removed.